# Getting most liked news from the query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are two models:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: news
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  title      :string           not null
#  content    :text             not null
#  scope      :string           not null
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  person_id  :integer          not null

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: likes
#
#  id        :integer          not null, primary key
#  like      :boolean
#  person_id :integer          not null
#  news_id   :integer          not null
```

Relation

```
news has many likes
like belongs to news
```

I want to get most liked news from query. Query should substract count of likes equal true from likes equal false. The highest number is most liked news.
What I tried:

```
@count_true_likes = Like.where('likes.like = ?', true).group(:news_id).count
@count_false_likes = Like.where('likes.like = ?', false).group(:news_id).count
```

Result is Hash with id and counted likes. I don't have idea how to subtract in query positive likes from negative likes, and do it for every news.

Comment: What DBMS you are using? MySQl/Postgresql ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Postgresql

Comment: Either follow the answer, or make this `Like.group(:news_id, :like).select(:news_id, :like, COUNT(like))` and then use it as an INNER query to build the actual result.

Comment: Your code result: ``NameError: undefined local variable or method `like' for main:Object

Comment: yeah I had many typos `Like.group(:news_id, :like).select("news_id, like, COUNT(like)")`

Comment: Now it's: `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","... like,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem:

```
@most_liked_news_id = Like.group(:news_id)
                          .select('news_id, SUM(case when likes.like then 1 else -1 end) as max_positive')
                          .order('max_positive desc').map(&:news_id).first
@most_liked_news = News.find(@most_liked_news_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

This kind of querying becomes prohibitively slow very quickly, as your dataset grows. A common workaround is to cache number of upvotes and downvotes. For example

```
# Table name: news
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  title      :string           not null
#  content    :text             not null
#  scope      :string           not null
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  person_id  :integer          not null
#
#  upvotes_count   :integer     not null
#  downvotes_count :integer     not null
#  vote_result     :integer     not null
```

Where `vote_result` is a cached `upvotes_count - downvotes_count`.

Then simply do

```
News.order(vote_result: :desc).limit(10) # top 10 articles
```

The downside is, of course, that you need to maintain those cached counters (increase/decrease corresponding ones when you register a vote).

Comment: @SergioTuelentsev thank you for your suggestion, but I don't want add extra columns in table.

Comment: @ŁukaszKorol: oh, no worries. You _will_ want soon :)